# Embed Asset Packs In Product Bundle, Xcode 9.2

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9.2, one-definition-rule

In previous versions of Xcode I was able to embed the asset packs in the product bundle for debugging of the ODR service. This option used to appear in BuildSettings/Assets:
[Enabling Embed Asset packs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5LCv.png)

But that option no longer appears to be there:
[Option no longer there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaLdY.png)

Is there a way to enable this again or has apple change the way you test ODR locally?

Comment: Search 'assets' in search box.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure under build settings where you can choose between "Basic, Customized, All, Combined, and Levels" that you have chosen both "All" and "Combined".  I'm using Xcode 9.4.1 and "Embed Asset Packs in Product Bundle" shows up when I have both of those selected.

[image: ODR Build Settings]